# Unable to Anonymously Login on Android O with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I do an anonymous login via Firebase in my SplashScreen and it works on most emulators and real devices that I have. I have tried it with 4.4 and 5.0 Emulators all Nexus 5. I also have a Moto G Play on 6.0.1 and it works on that too. For some reason it does not work on Android O emulator and a Samsung Galaxy S5 running 6.0.1

Here's my code to do this on `SplashScreenActivity` :

```
if (fUser == null) {

            fAuth.signInAnonymously()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                Log.d("ReacherNull", "reached");
                                Log.d("AnonLogin", "singInAnonymously:success" + user.getUid().toString());
                                Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Anon Sign in: Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Anon Sign in: Failed, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                //noinspection ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                                Log.d("Anon Failed Error", "" + task.getException());


                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    })

                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("Exception on SignIn", "exception: " + e);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Log.d("Reacher!Null", "reached");
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
```

The `if` statement is triggered on `fUser` being null and I know this because I have logged after it before. It hasn't returned me any exception even on `OnFailureListener`

Comment: Check the logcat output for `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.

Comment: @BobSnyder Yes I do see it, is there a way to force the user to update it or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase, being part of the Google Play SDK, relies on capabilities provided by Google Play services.  This is [noted in the Firebase Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play).  Some Firebase features fail if a compatible version of Google Play Services is not present on the device or emulator.  When a compatible version is not present a warning message is output to logcat:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date
```

An app can check for the presence of a compatible version of Google Play Services and initiate processing to install the needed version using the methods of class [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability).  For example:

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this /*activity*/)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Play Services OKAY");
                } else {
                    // TODO Show the user some UI explaining that the needed version
                    // of Play Services could not be installed and the app can't run.
                    Log.w(TAG, "onComplete: App can't run without Play Services");
                }
            }
        });
```